# Remove pattern from string with gsub

Tags: r, gsub

I am struggling to remove the substring before the underscore in my string.
I want to use * (wildcard) as the bit before the underscore can vary:

```
a <- c("foo_5", "bar_7")

a <- gsub("*_", "", a, perl = TRUE)
```

The result should look like:

```
> a
[1] 5 7
```

I also tried stuff like "^**" or "?*" but did not really work.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The following code works on your example :

```
gsub(".*_", "", a)
```

Comment: great thanks. What does the '.' stands for? Why does the star "*" (wildcard) does not work by its own? I don't understand?

Comment: '.' stands for any character, so that ".*" stands for any number of any character. You can find more explanations by typing `?regex`.

Comment: Ah I see! I thought * includes the meaning of the '.' already! Well, now I know better. thanks again!

Comment: For clarification, you are confusing the regular expression (regex) syntax with glob syntax; both use the * star character as a wild card, but it means slightly different things between the two.

Answer (score 8):

**Alternatively, you can also try:**

```
gsub("\\S+_", "", a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to point out that there is an approach using functions from the `tidyverse`, which I find more readable than `gsub`:

```
a %>% stringr::str_remove(pattern = ".*_")
```

Comment: a is a vector not a dataframe. This would result in the following error: 'Warning message:
In stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing"

Answer (score -2):

```
as.numeric(gsub(pattern=".*_", replacement = '', a)
[1] 5 7
```

Comment: Always add explanation to your answer besides the code for better understanding