# How do I remove the text [start section id="20107"] from a column in a dataframe

Tags: r, string, gsub, substitution

I am trying to remove the string `[start section id="20107"]` that appears in every cell of a column in a dataframe.

I have tried `df1$Col1<- gsub("[start section id="20107"]", "", df1$Col1)`but I got an error `unexpected numeric constant in df1$Col1<- gsub("[start section id="20107"` , not sure what else I can try, any help is appreciated folks.

```
[start section id="20107"]

(11-Feb-2013 13:22 DK04)
#1 Preventive exam
#2 Mild hyperlipidemia
#3 Hyperglycemia
#4 Peripheral neuropathy
```

Comment: It's hard to help you without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please provide it. My guess is that you're dealing with factors and not with strings, but seeing some data (by doing dput(head(data)) would make things easier.

Comment: @Heroka, good point , I have added a snippet of the string below my question.hope this works.

Comment: At the very least you need to escape the double quotes in your pattern.

Comment: @Jay, escaping ?? not sure how to do that

Comment: `df1$Col1 <- gsub( '[start section id="20107"]', "", df1$Col1, fixed=TRUE)` ?

Comment: Should be marked as Replicated. Asked before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704213/r-remove-part-of-string), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776287/remove-pattern-from-string-with-gsub), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936339/in-r-how-do-i-replace-text-within-a-string) just to give a few examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gsub` requires regular expression, so `[` are treated as special regex-char. use `fixed = TRUE`. Furthermore, you have to escape quotation marks with `\`, so use `\"` if you have `"` in strings.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Col1 = "fdsfd [start section id=\"20107\"]")
df1$Col1<- gsub("[start section id=\"20107\"]", "", df1$Col1, fixed = TRUE)
```

With `fixed = TRUE`, your search pattern is considered as "plain string", not as regular expression.

Comment: thats it Dan it came through.

Comment: you should provide some of the many examples where the solution was presented before on SO.

Answer (score 2):

The `pattern` in `gsub` is messed up because of the nested double quotes.
Either escape the quotes around the numbers or use single quotes around the pattern. Also use `fixed = TRUE` as you are not trying to match a regular expression but a fix pattern.

```
gsub('[start section id="20107"]', "", df1$Col1, fixed = TRUE)
```