# Trouble with a specific character (’) in R

Tags: r

## Problem

I have been working on merging and standardizing several survey datasets. One problem that I'm running across is that there is inconsistent use of punctuation. Sometimes, the research is coded with a standard `'`, and other times is coded with `’`.

For example, the names of the Ivory Coast in French is Côte d'Ivoire. Unfortunately, the data are not uniformly coded across time. As a result, when I run a crosstab, I get this:

```
country         2008      2009
-------         ----      ----
Cote d'Ivoire    498        0
Cote d’Ivoire     0        502
```

What I **want** to get is this:

```
country         2008      2009
-------         ----      ----
Cote d'Ivoire    498       502
```

When I try to standardize these to use the `'` rather than the `’`, I have absolutely no luck. It just doesn't seem to do anything. Here is the code I would use:

```
data$country[data$country == "Cote d’Ivoire"] <- Cote d'Ivoire
```

For some reason, I can't seem to figure this out, and it's driving me nuts. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: firt what does `sum(data$country == "Cote d’Ivoire")` return?

Comment: Well, I think I figure it out! I used `trimws()` to see whether there was perhaps some extra blank space in there, and it seems to have fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

you can replace a value with another value  using gsub

```
data$country=gsub("’","'",data$country)
```

In case it doesnt work you may need to escape the special character using a double backslash

```
data$country=gsub("\\’","'",data$country)
```

See

[Remove pattern from string with gsub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776287/remove-pattern-from-string-with-gsub)

Comment: It should be the other way round. He/She is trying to replace with '

Comment: Thank you both very much. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I'll keep plugging away.

Comment: You need to determine if indeed `’` exists. use `grep` and if it does exist then this code provided here might work

Comment: Dear @Onyambu - Thank you! I will figure out how to use grep.